# Jquery change function after replacing select boxes with twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, onchange, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/xuAQv/ <-- Link to my bad code on JsFiddle.

So i found this bit of code which coverts traditional form select boxes into their twitter bootstrap styled versions.   It essentially just hides the select, and creates the html for a select box using bootstrap's css / js.

http://blog.iamjamoy.com/convert-select-boxes-to-a-fancy-html-dropdown
I customized the plugin a bit to change the appearance of the drop downs.

The problem i have now is that the $("#mySelect").change(function(){}); no longer fires.
I tried adding .live to it, and .on to it, without any luck.

Do i need to modify the plugin?
Here is my code for the plugin..

```
/*!
 * Convert <select> elements to Dropdown Group
 *
 * Author: John Rocela 2012 <me@iamjamoy.com>
 * Customized: Frank B 3/2012
 */
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('select').each(function (i, e) {
        if (!($(e).data('convert') == 'no')) {
            //get some initial data...
            xSelect = $(e).attr('id')
            xLabel = $("#" + xSelect + " option:selected").text();
            xClass = $(e).data('class')
            $(e).hide().wrap('<div class="btn-group" id="select-group-' + i + '" />');
            var select = $('#select-group-' + i);
            select.html('<a class="btn dropdown-toggle ' + xClass + '" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;">' + xLabel + ' <span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul><input type="hidden" value="' + $(e).val() + '" name="' + $(e).attr('name') + '" id="' + $(e).attr('id') + '" class="' + $(e).attr('class') + '" />');
            $(e).find('option').each(function (o, q) {
                select.find('.dropdown-menu').append('<li><a href="javascript:;" data-title="' + $(q).text() + '" data-value="' + $(q).attr('value') + '">' + $(q).text() + '</a></li>');
                if ($(q).attr('selected')) select.find('.dropdown-menu li:eq(' + o + ')').click();
            });
            select.find('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
                select.find('input[type=hidden]').live().val($(this).data('value')).change();
                select.find('.btn:eq(0)').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is "mydiv" supposed to be?  I'm guessing that's not actually the selector you're using?

Comment: @James, thanks fixed it.  It is suppose to be the ID of the select box before it has the bootstrap treatment added by the plugin.

Comment: Strange, seems like using `live` or properly using `on` should have worked.  The select is replaced by a hidden input, but that input has the same `id` as the select.  Are you sure you passed just the `id` as a selector to `live`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xuAQv/ - Realized how to use JsFiddle.

Comment: @JamesMontagne it is probably because I am not smart enough to figure out where the Jquery .on needs to be coded.  Can it be put into the plugin or does it have to go into the .change() function?

Comment: I see the problem, you're using `live` wrong.  Answer incoming.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10051/discussion-between-frank-and-james-montagne)

Comment: Updated fiddle in case anyone needs to see a working version:
http://jsfiddle.net/xuAQv/425/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at what is actually happening in the code, the select is being replaced by a hidden input.  When you change the value, that is what is getting `change()` called on it.  You will need to use event delegation.  Something like this:

```
$("<parent selector>").on("change","#mySelect", function(){});
```

Where `<parent selector>` is a selector matching some parent of the select which is not replaced.  If needed it can be the `document` but ideally you want it to be as far down the tree as possible.

---

The reason your `live` didn't work is because it should have been like this:

```
$("#mySelect").live("change", function(){});
```

Though you should not use `live` if you are using the latest jquery, you should use `on`.

---

**EDIT:** Updated your fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xuAQv/2/

Comment: thanks @James, the only problem i have now is that I cannot pull the .val().   Within the function, when i try: 
myval = $('optDeposit').val(); - It just remains undefined.